# Similar to Page Load Event - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to display a list in a div when the view is loaded. I am new to MVC
and I don't know where or how to do it. I know I Need to do HTTP POST but how?
Thank you for your help.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="online">
    </div>
</div>
```

A nudge to the right direction would help me. Thank you

Comment: What you are asking cannot be done with just two div, I think that you have to start from the beginning, please try those tutorial:

 [ASP.NET Razor - C# and VB Code Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp)  and also 

[HTML Tutorial](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/)

Please post some more code, we will be happy to help you !

Comment: I will do more research. Thank you Sir